# PHP fill form inside while loop from a SQL table

Tags: php, loops, drop-down-menu

I'm using a while loop to fill a drop down menu with options from a SQL table but my old friend PHP responds with a lovely blank page.

What am I doing wrong? Probably something completely obvious..

```
<?php
include("DbConnect.php");
$Query = "SELECT VehNo, Make_Model FROM vehicle
order by VehNo";
$Result = mysql_select_query($DB,$Query);

echo'<label>';
echo'<select name = "Vehicle">';
while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result))
 {
 echo'<option value ='".$Row["VehNo"]."'>'".$Row["Make_Model"]."'</option>';
 }
echo'</label>';
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
<form method="POST" action="detailsShow.php">

<?php
include("DbConnect.php");
$Query = "SELECT VehNo, Make_Model FROM vehicle
order by VehNo";
$Result = mysql_query($DB,$Query);

echo'<label>';
echo'<select name = "Vehicle">';
while ($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))
 {
echo'<option value ='".$Row["VehNo"]."'>".$Row["Make_Model"]."</option>';
 }
echo'</label>';
?>

<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="see a nice piccy of the car">
</FORM>
```

Comment: thats why you always turn on error reporting. the syntax highlighter already shows it

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
echo'<option value ='".$Row["VehNo"]."'>'".$Row["Make_Model"]."'</option>';
```

to:

```
echo "<option value =\"{$Row['VehNo']}\">{$Row['Make_Model']}</option>";
```

and it should work.

Also enable errors for the next time.